# Keystore -- Customized SecretKey entry into Keystore from command line

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, aes, keytool

As part of encrypting and saving data, we have generated KEY's using AES algorithm with openssl.

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -P -nosalt
```

Openssl has generated KEY & IV values, which are been stored in a plain text file. Since, storing of keys in a plain document is a not secure standard, thought of moving it to Keystore.

Therefore, we have generated a Keystore using keytool by executing the below command.

```
keytool -genseckey -keyalg AES -alias aesstore -keysize 256 -keypass changeit -storetype jceks -keystore hello.jceks -storepass changeit
```

This Keystore holds a random secrey key. So, we wanted to move our KEY & IV values to the Keystore, so that we can fetch from there and use them for encryption of data.  I have found below link for storing customized KEY value to Keystore, but not the IV value.

http://java.dzone.com/articles/secret-key-import-java

Hence, if any one has any ideas on how to store both KEY & IV values to keystore., please do share.

Also, we are looking for a way, where we can pass the customized keys to keystore from the command line itself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

IV's should be unique every time you use the key within a mode of operation. Storing the IV with the key does therefore not make much sense. If you have to you could extract an IV for CBC from a key using a hash function, but you should then only encrypt once with the key and generated IV.

Usually a random IV is generated and prefixed to the ciphertext. When passwords are used then they are usually paired with a random salt. If a new random salt is generated for each encryption operation, then specifying a fully random IV would be spurious. In that case the IV may be derived from the salt. In that case the salt is usually prefixed to the ciphertext instead.

So you are looking for an option to store a persistent IV, while the IV has been defined to change for each encryption. This is why you won't find a solution in a key store implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understood that IV is an ever changing value in key store implementation. The problem for us is, currently, we have been using persistent KEY & IV value for encrypting & saving data. If we move our KEY to Keystore, the data that we encrypt doesn't match with previous encrypted data for a same string, as the IV value is different. So,to solve this I think the only solution is, to extract key from Keystore and with the help of persistent IV, encrypt the data. Please suggest.

Comment: You should change your protocol and just store a key in the end. But for now you could hack your way out of it and store the IV as e.g. AES-128 key. Then you get back the bytes using `aesKey.getEncoded()`. AES keys consists of fully random data and will just return the bytes as they were put in.